# Mastering HTML Element positioning w.r.t viewports and regions

Tags: javascript, viewport, region

I'm trying hard to get good hands-on on positioning html elements with respect to viewport and regions and wanted to master on stuff like viewport, region, offsetLeft, offsetTop etc...

May have to work on sooner on the scenarios like 'Positioning an element depending on the viewport size (desktops, tablets and smartphones)' or 'Making sure the element is always positioned within the viewport irrespective of the form factor' etc...

Would be of great help if you can point me to some good resources to get strong knowledge on this stuff using plain javascript and don't want to rely on any framework out there.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: This question is too broad for this site; check something like [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com) or [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/) for likely sources of useful information.

Comment: For most cases you would _not_ use JavaScript for this, but CSS media queries … so the premise of your question seems to be off already.

Comment: Agree, but we want to implement the stuff in a form-factor-agnostic way and write less media-queries as much as possible to avoid maintenance forks.